# Access is denied while running a C program file

Tags: c, mingw

```
S:\C>gcc update.c -o update

S:\C>.\update.exe
Access is denied.
```

The code in the file

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct fish {
        char name;
        int id1;
        int id2;
        float f1;
        double d1;
        double d2;
        double d3;
    };
    struct fish f;
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(f));
    printf("%d\n", &f.name);
    printf("%d\n", &f.id1);
    printf("%d\n", &f.id2);
    printf("%d\n", &f.f1);
    printf("%d\n", &f.d1);
    printf("%d\n", &f.d2);
    printf("%d\n", &f.d3);
    return 0;
}
```

When i installed the `MinGW` it worked fine for few days(even the anti virus real time protection is on) and now it is giving me `Access is denied` error when the antivirus real time protection is on or off.

What might be the problems?

Comment: What happens if you copy `update.exe` to some other computer and run it there?

Comment: This does not seem to be a C problem... I believe your OS is denying access to the executable.

Comment: When i run the code on online editior it is running correctly.

Comment: @g_bor Is there a way to get rid of this problem

Comment: At first I would try to run it from my user's directory, and make sure that ownership and access controls are set up right. You can find a bit of information about this error here: https://windowsreport.com/access-is-denied-windows-10/

Comment: @Anonymous yes, there is certainly a way to get rid of the problem. But first you need to answer the questions in the previous comments, otherways we can't help much. Anyway, for me the prime suspect is the antivirus. Often they still stay active to some extent even if they are "deactivated". Also tell us which antivirus you're using.

Comment: It's worth noting that the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) provides a *vastly* better experience than MinGW so if you're not too heavily invested you may want to look at that alternative.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have turned off my McAfee real time protection.

Comment: Just to check, try powershell you should use `./update.exe`, or a regular command line remove the `./`, just `update.exe`.

Comment: Remove all programs that take over your computer, lag it down, prevent other programs from working correctly and cause damage in general. Doesn't matter if you call them virus or anti-virus, they need to be removed.

Comment: @anastaciu No it does not worked

Comment: @Anonymous, that's too bad, something in your system is not leting run the program, it's hard to say what it is for sure, search online for the keywords maybe someone has the same issue.

Comment: @anastaciu did you do what I suggested in my very first comment? Also try to send your update.exe to https://www.virustotal.com/gui/, could be interesting to see what happens

Comment: Yes! But it giving me the same error

Comment: @Anonymous submit your update.exe to  https://www.virustotal.com/gui/ and report what happens

Comment: No one has detected to be a virus

Comment: The problem is when i first installed `mingw` the compilation process has done as expected without giving me any errors but today suddenly it started to give me this error. I aslo tried to reinstall but it does not helped

Comment: @Anonymous BTW there is a problem in your code, the `printf`'s are ill-formed, `printf("%d\n", &f.name);`, you should remove the `&` operator, and you should initialize the structure before printing, `struct fish f = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, did you pinged me on purpose or you meant to ping Anonymous?

Comment: @anastaciu I meant Anonymous, sorry

Comment: @anastaciu I have tried to run different c programs that were executed yesterday but suddenly they are executing today.

Comment: @Anonymous, you mean they *aren't executing* right? Anyway, I was just pointing out the problems in the code, when you fix the problem you should also then fix that code. One other thing you should try, if you haven't already, is to give your executable a different name.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the C: drive in your PC, click *Properties -> Security -> Advanced* button, Find owner section (which is **TrustedInstaller**) and click *Change*. Click *Advance* and then *Find Now*. Scroll to find your user (Or type your username under "Enter the object name").

[image]

Now click the *OK* button, make sure "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" is **unchecked**, click *OK*, click the *Edit...* button, click on your username, check the "Full control" box, then click "OK" on both open Dialog.

Note that you must have enough permission to do that.