# Getting error in structure in c programing

Tags: c

I don't know why , but my code runs properly only for once,
if i run it again it gives me this error.

Code and the error is given below :

```
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
int main()
{
    struct date d;

    printf("E:");
    scanf("%d", &d.month);

    printf("E:");
    scanf("%d", &d.day);

    printf("E:");
    scanf("%d", &d.year);

    printf("The date is as\n");
    printf("%d/%d/%d", d.month, d.day, d.year);

    return 0;
}
```

error which i am getting after running it second time is :

```
Program 'structure.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 
char:91
+ ...  ; if ($?) { gcc structure.c -o structure } ; if ($?) {         
.\structure }
+                                                                     
At line:1 char:91
+ ...  ; if ($?) { gcc structure.c -o structure } ; if ($?) {         
.\structure }
+                                                                     
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], Applicatio 
   nFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: But I'd start from checking your antivirus log.

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: @Raj now i have added the code .

Comment: @bereal also why i am getting antivirus notification whenever i run this program.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't issue with C, but rather with your OS. [Bereal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770830/bereal) has good point with checking antivirus.

I have no problems with this code myself:
https://onlinegdb.com/C-rjGTWuT

Next time, please make sure there aren't simmilar topics already:
[Access is denied while running a C program file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63932532/access-is-denied-while-running-a-c-program-file)